# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list rails 5.2.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am developing a simple Rails application. I need to do a request with ajax but it not working. I have jquery-rails and I added jquery references in application.js (requires)

```
    <%= form_with(model: article, local: true) do |form| %>
        <%= form.select(:resource_id, [['Opc 1',1],['Opc 2',2]]) %>
        <script>
        $('select#article_resource_id').on('change', function(event) {
            var selected_resource_id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax('/relative/path/to/your/action', data: { id: selected_resource_id })
        })
        </script>
    <% end %>
```

This is my error:
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax('/relative/path/to/your/action', data: { id: selected_resource_id })
```

should be

```
$.ajax('/relative/path/to/your/action', { data: { id: selected_resource_id } })
```

The second argument is expected to be the settings, of which `data` is the object's key word for the elements that go in the query string.

Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/